# Guardar en varias colecciones Mongoose misma llamada

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Necesito guardar al mismo tiempo en un mismo método de mi API la información de mis Arrays [data_inver],[asociar_inver] en Mongoosee.

Ahora mismo estoy lanzando estos dos metodos:

```
// save multiple documents to the collection referenced by Data_Greenhouse Model
    data_Greenhouse.collection.insert(data_inver, function (err, docs) {
      if (err){
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
      } else {
        console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection");
        res.status(200).send({data_Greenhouse: docs})

      }
    });

    // save multiple documents to the collection referenced by asociar_Greenhouse Model
    asociar_Greenhouse.collection.insert(asociar_inver, function (err, docs) {
      if (err){
        res.status(500).send({message: 'Error al guardar en la base de datos'})
      } else {
        console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection");
        res.status(200).send({asociar_Greenhouse: docs})

      }
    });
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como decirle que guarde en diferentes colecciones con una sola llamada, ya que el error me lo da al lanzar los dos uno detrás del otro, ya que da error en las cabeceras por que la petición ya fue enviada.

¿Es posible guardar múltiples documentos en diferentes colecciones en una misma llamada a mongo?

Todo esto lo estoy haciendo sobre NodeJS.

Gracias un saludo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, parece que el error estaba en que lanzo dos respuestas al guardar cada una de ella, he eliminado una y ya si funciona correctamente. Aun así no si existe una forma mejor de realizar esta inserción. gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la libreria [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/), especificamente el método [parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) el cual te ayudará a ejecutar los 2 inserts. Una vez que se hayan ejecutado los dos, tendrias un callback con posibles errores o resultados de los inserts.

Ej:

```
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'one');
        }, 200);
    },
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 'two');
        }, 100);
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results) {
    // the results array will equal ['one','two'] even though
    // the second function had a shorter timeout.
});

// an example using an object instead of an array
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 1);
        }, 200);
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            callback(null, 2);
        }, 100);
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    // results is now equals to: {one: 1, two: 2}
});
```